# How to write string on .Doc file

Tags: python, string, doc

How to write string to .Doc file using python?
`<class 'str'>` 
 i need like `.to_csv(),to_json()` method to create doc file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use python-docx module

Sample code from https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_run('bold').bold = True
p.add_run(' and some ')
p.add_run('italic.').italic = True

document.add_heading('Heading, level 1', level=1)
document.add_paragraph('Intense quote', style='Intense Quote')

document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in unordered list', style='List Bullet'
)
document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in ordered list', style='List Number'
)

#don'thave picture on my pc
#document.add_picture('monty-truth.png', width=Inches(1.25))

records = (
    (3, '101', 'Spam'),
    (7, '422', 'Eggs'),
    (4, '631', 'Spam, spam, eggs, and spam')
)

table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Qty'
hdr_cells[1].text = 'Id'
hdr_cells[2].text = 'Desc'
for qty, id, desc in records:
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = str(qty)
    row_cells[1].text = id
    row_cells[2].text = desc

document.add_page_break()

document.save('data/demo.docx')
```

Comment: i using here `recognize_google` for audio convert to text .i want set font for that. have you any idea set font for `recognize_google`

Comment: i mean hove can set font for that like style?

Comment: document.add_paragraph( 'first item in ordered list', style='List Number',font='Alian') can i get like this?

Comment: Once take a look at it: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html#apply-character-formatting